# Unexpected LNK 2019 in C++ class

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, linker, lnk2019

I'm encountering the following linker issue when I try to build my project.

I've had a look through the other posts here and as far as I can see, the only externals I'm using are members of standard (and identified with std::), or primitives. Is there something obvious that I'm missing here?

Building using Eclipse C++ (Mars) on Win 7 professional 64bit using the internal eclipse builder.

Log:

> link /debug /nologo /OUT:SAD-Snoop.exe "src\ByteScanner.obj" "src\EncType.obj" "src\SAD-Snoop.obj" "src\SearchHits.obj"
>
> SearchHits.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall SearchHits::GetHitAddress(unsigned int)" (GetHitAddress@SearchHits@@QAEJI@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall SearchHits::Merge(class SearchHits)" (?Merge@SearchHits@@QAE_NV1@@Z)
>
> SAD-Snoop.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>
> 14:28:44 Build Finished (took 909ms)

Header:

```
/*
 * SearchHits.h
 *
 *  Created on: 30 Jun 2015
 *      Author: Nick Boyd
 */

#ifndef SEARCHHITS_H_
#define SEARCHHITS_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class SearchHits {
public:
    SearchHits();
    ~SearchHits();
    bool AddHit(std::string content, long address);
    unsigned int CountHits();
    std::string GetHit(unsigned int hitNumber);
    long GetHitAddress(unsigned int hitNumber);
    bool Merge(SearchHits hits);
private:
    std::vector<std::string> hits;
    std::vector<long> hitAddresses;
};

#endif /* SEARCHHITS_H_ */
```

class:

```
/*
 * SearchHits.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 30 Jun 2015
 *      Author: Nick Boyd
 */

#include "SearchHits.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> hitContents;
std::vector<long> hitAddresses;

SearchHits::SearchHits() {
}

SearchHits::~SearchHits() {
    hitContents.clear();
    hitAddresses.clear();
}

bool SearchHits::AddHit(std::string hitContent, long address) {
    hitContents.push_back(hitContent);
    hitAddresses.push_back(address);
    return ((hitContents.back() == hitContent)
            && (hitAddresses.back() == address));
}

unsigned int SearchHits::CountHits() {
    return hitContents.size();
}

std::string SearchHits::GetHit(unsigned int hitNumber) {
    if (hitNumber < hitContents.size()) {
        return hitContents[hitNumber];
    } else {
        std::cout << "Error in Function [SearchHits::GetHit()]" << std::endl
                << "Parameter [hitNumber] out of bounds: "
                << hitNumber + " Upper Limit: " << hitContents.size()
                << std::endl;
        throw new std::invalid_argument(
                "Error in Function [SearchHits::GetHit()] Parameter [hitNumber] out of bounds: "
                + std::to_string(hitNumber));
    }
}

long GetHitAddress(unsigned int hitNumber) {
    if (hitNumber < hitContents.size()) {
        return hitAddresses[hitNumber];
    } else {
        std::cout << "Error in Function [SearchHits::GetHitAddress()]"
                << std::endl << "Parameter [hitNumber] out of bounds: "
                << hitNumber << " Upper Limit: " << hitContents.size()
                << std::endl;
        throw new std::invalid_argument(
                "Error in Function [SearchHits::GetHitAddress()] Parameter [hitNumber] out of bounds: "
                + std::to_string(hitNumber));
    }
}

bool SearchHits::Merge(SearchHits hits) {
    bool overallResult = true;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    while ((i < hits.CountHits()) && overallResult) {
        bool tempResult = false;
        unsigned char attemptNum = 1;
        while ((tempResult == false) && (attemptNum++ <= 5)) {
            tempResult = this->AddHit(hits.GetHit(i),hits.GetHitAddress(i));
        }
        overallResult = (overallResult && tempResult);
        ++i;
    }
    if (overallResult) {
        hits.~SearchHits();
    }
    return overallResult;
}
```

Comment: `SearchHits::GetHitAddress` You've been missing the class scope in definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
long GetHitAddress(unsigned int hitNumber)
```

to

```
long SearchHits::GetHitAddress(unsigned int hitNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks, it was something obvious after all.
(Transitioning from Java, PHP & AS3)